# Where to download spring ws sample with Maven build and xml configuration?

Tags: spring, maven, sample

I download spring ws sample from the link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws-samples. All sample projects use Gradle build and java configuration. I am looking for the spring ws sample codes which uses Maven and xml configuration.

Comment: What if these are not available for Maven and XML?

Answer (score 0):

This link http://sourceforge.net/p/springframework/svn/14604/tree/spring-ws/tags/ contains spring ws packages and samples from version 0.9 to 1.55 with Maven build and xml configuration.